Monthly Automatic Replica Replacement in Azure Container App
I am running my application in Azure Container Apps, and I have observed that, each month, old replicas are automatically destroyed and new replicas are created within the same revision across different environments but within the same region. This typically happens around the same time each month. Could you please confirm if this behavior is due to scheduled Azure platform maintenance or another underlying process?

July 2024:

Atom: 7/23/2024, 10:25:08 AM

Visualization: 7/23/2024, 12:11:24 PM

Admin: 7/23/2024, 12:34:38 PM

Notification: 7/23/2024, 12:34:38 PM

WMS: 7/23/2024, 12:34:43 PM

Webapp: 7/23/2024, 12:58:02 PM

Dashboard: 7/23/2024, 12:58:17 PM

Webapp Nginx: 7/23/2024, 10:56:49 AM

UI: 7/23/2024, 11:47:58 AM

Tenant Service: 7/23/2024, 11:48:14 AM

Keycloakgateway: 7/23/2024, 12:58:05 PM


August 2024:

Webapp: 8/22/2024, 9:59:24 AM

Atom: 8/22/2024, 10:46:48 AM

Dashboard: 8/22/2024, 11:17:02 AM

Admin: 8/22/2024, 11:49:55 AM

WMS: 8/22/2024, 11:50:01 AM

Notification: 8/22/2024, 12:39:11 PM

Visualization: 8/22/2024, 12:39:17 PM

Webapp Nginx: 8/22/2024, 10:47:07 AM

Tenant Service: 8/22/2024, 12:39:08 PM

Keycloakgateway: 8/22/2024, 12:39:08 PM

UI: 8/22/2024, 1:03:21 PM



Please advise if this is expected behavior related to Azure maintenance or if there are other factors involved.
Thanks in advance.

Yes you are correct, it is possible that the behavior observed in Azure Container Apps is related to routine maintenance for the underlying platform, routine maintenance for Azure App Service can cause updates to the platform and service, which may result in cold starts or interruptions. The regular replacement of replicas you observe is a typical outcome of these maintenance operations. If you want to be notified in advance about such maintenance activities or understand more about how they might impact your specific deployments, you can subscribe to Azure Service Health notifications. This will provide you with more context on when and why such events occur.
References:

Routine (planned) maintenance for Azure App Service
Planned maintenance notifications for Virtual Machine Scale Sets
Application lifecycle management in Azure Container Apps

